# How many address does a computer have to identify?

Tags: networking, identification

It's well known there is the IP address (ipv4 or ipv6) and the MAC address, but does it exist another addresses?

Comment: Well,there are port numbers too!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP address and MAC are related to Network Interfaces (Wifi interface, Ethernet ,PPP..), and PC could have many interfaces .